# separate a word into characters using string methods

Tags: iphone

Trying to split what the user writes in the text field, into an array full of the characters in the things he typed.

here is what I have so far

```
-(IBAction) generateFlashNow:(id)sender{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
NSString *string1 = textField.text;
NSString *string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@","];
NSArray *arrayOfLetters = [string2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"Log Array :%@", arrayOfLetters);

//NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Log First Letter of array: %@",[arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:0]);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is not doing anything when you pass an empty string "" so `string2` is an identical copy of `string1`, hence no commas and the split operation fails.

There are many ways to get this done. I can think of two:

Convert to a character array:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello";
const char *characters = [string UTF8String];
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(characters); i++) {
    NSLog(@"%c", characters[i]);
}
```

Or, if you only want to deal with objects, loop through each method and hand-create the array:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello";
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    NSString *myChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
    [array addObject:myChar];
}
```

You could add the above logic to a method like `toArray` as a category in NSString itself, so all strings get this functionality if that's a common case for your application. Checkout this [article](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) for more information about categories. You'd simply call `[someString toArray]` to get it's array representation.